# Logitech G502 Hero Scripting

Tags: lua, scripting, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to archive No Recoil in Pubg Mobile Emulator game via G Hub(Logitech App) mouse script... When I press fire button, it should keep on firing and keep my aim down. I wrote some code to aim down while firing and it works everywhere except in Pubg Mobile Emulator. In Pubg Mobile Emulator, It works in single shot but not in Auto Fire. Can anyone help me with this?

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
        recoil = not recoil
        spot = not spot
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
        if recoil then
            repeat
                --Sleep(10)
                Sleep(10)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 5)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Probably there are no "Pubg Mobile Emulator" users on this site.  You'd better ask on game-specific forum.  Or you should explain what is the difference between "single shot" and "Auto Fire" in "Pubg Mobile Emulator".

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine gets the job done.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock" ) and false then -- change false to true to enable
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0,3)
                Sleep(10)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
end
```

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
-- OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg);
-- OutputLogMessage(""..tostring(IsMouseButtonPressed(3)).."\n")
if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
end

if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") and (IsMouseButtonPressed(3) or IsMouseButtonPressed(5)) then
    recoil = true
else
    recoil = false
end

if (recoil and IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then
    multiplier = 1.00
    Sleep(10)
    repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(0, multiplier * 3)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(0, multiplier * 2)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(0, multiplier * 3)
        multiplier = multiplier + 0.02
        OutputLogMessage("M: %f \n", multiplier);
        Sleep(5)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
```

end